# Navigation Bar removeGestureRecognizer is not removing the Guesture

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

I need to add Tap Gesture on Navigation Bar or View.
I got the below solution which works perfectly fine.

But `removeGestureRecognizer` is not removing the gesture and it's breaking the functionality of other back buttons in other view controllers.

How to fix the issue?

```
var taskTodoOnBar : UITapGestureRecognizer!

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    navigationController?.view.addGestureRecognizer(taskTodoOnBar)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)
{
    navigationController?.view.removeGestureRecognizer(taskTodoOnBar)
}
```

Or

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    navigationController?.navigationBar.addGestureRecognizer(taskTodoOnBar)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)
{
    navigationController?.navigationBar.removeGestureRecognizer(taskTodoOnBar)
}
```

When I try to get gestureRecognizers count, It says nil. Then where is the gesture being added ?

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)
{  
   print(navigationController!.view.gestureRecognizers!.count)
   print(navigationController!.navigationBar.gestureRecognizers!.count)
}
```

Comment: Hey Sujay, have you tried to list the gestures array from the view, e.g
navigationController?.navigationBar.gestureRecognizers to check if is the array ok?

Comment: The navigationBar.gestureRecognizers count is nil. Have added the same in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this

**Declared gesture as**

```
let tapGesture : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
```

**Gesture Handler**

```
@objc func tapHandler(handler: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("gesture Added")
    }
```

**Added in Navigation bar as**

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(VC2.tapHandler(handler:)))
        self.navigationController?.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
```

**Removed as**

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        for gesture in (navigationController?.view.gestureRecognizers)! {
            if gesture == tapGesture {
                navigationController?.view.removeGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
                print("removed")
            }
        }
    }
```

**Updated Answer for - gesture count prints nil**

console Output :

[image]

Comment: navigationController?.view.gestureRecognizers is returning nil. So have added the same in question.

Comment: check updated Code - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hFDjIPox7lC83dCBPadugWdmEJZWcxu1

Comment: I posted new link here earlier one was not working when downloaded

Comment: Yes inside ViewDidLoad even I got same. Can you try to print the same in viewWillDisappear. Add all code in VC3. So when u come back to VC2, Back Button on VC2 to should work and take you to VC1

Comment: let me check please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163682/discussion-between-sujay-u-n-and-ios-geek).

Answer (score 0):

After help from iOS Geek, I figured out that, gestureRecognizers!.count was 2 in ViewdDidLoad but was nil inside viewWillDisappear.

Then I dug more and discovered that I had written the custom code for my back button.

So in such case, we Should removeGestureRecognizer before popToViewController

So this is for all whom I wish not to make mistake like me while using the custom back button.

```
func backBarBtnFnc(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
{
    navigationController?.navigationBar.removeGestureRecognizer(taskTodoOnBar)

    // CodTdo ...

    self.navigationController!.popToViewController(VC2, animated: true)
}
```